# python3 npyscreen очистка FormBaseNew

Tags: python-3.x

Столкнулся с вопросом очистки введенных значений формы `npyscreen.FormBaseNew`,
пример кода отражающего проблему:

```
class MyApplication(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm('MAIN',MainMenuForm1, name='Главное меню 1.0')
        self.addForm('FORM2',MenuForm2,name='Форма 2.0')


class BackButtonWithCleanForm(npyscreen.ButtonPress):
    def __init__(self, *args, **keywords):
        super(BackButtonWithCleanForm, self).__init__(*args, **keywords)
        self.name = 'Вернутся назад'
        self.label_width = len(self.name)
    def whenPressed(self):
        self.parent.parentApp.switchForm(None) #переключение на другую форму 
        #как реализовать здесь очистку формы при переключении на другую форму?

class MainMenuForm1(npyscreen.FormBaseNew):
    def create(self):
        self.changekey = self.add(npyscreen.TitleFilenameCombo,name='example')
        self.backbutton = self.add(BackButtonWithCleanForm, scroll_exit = True)

class MenuForm2(npyscreen.FormBaseNew):
    def create(self):
        self.actionwithkey = self.add(npyscreen.TitleSelectOne,values=["1","2"], 
                        name="example2",
                        scroll_exit=True,max_height = 4)
        self.backbutton = self.add(BackButtonWithCleanForm, scroll_exit = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp = MyApplication().run()
```

этот код написан для наглядности

Как реализовать очистку формы при переключении на другую форму? В настоящем коде программы в форме есть кнопка "назад" и реализован переход на предыдущую форму , но при нажатии кнопки "назад" , введенные в поля формы значения остаются,и отображаются при следующем переходе на эту форму, что является недостатком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.в библиотеке npyscreen , в классе NPSAppManaged , добавить

```
def getThisForm(self):
    return self._THISFORM
```

решение:

```
a = self.parent.parentApp.getThisForm() 
for _w in a._widgets__:
    if hasattr(_w,'set_value'):
            _w.value=None
    if hasattr(_w,'get_value_as_list'):
            _w.value=''
```